# List comprehensions with class objects

Tags: python, class, object, list-comprehension

I have a class named StrucData in subfile.py

```
class StrucData:  
def __init__(self, name):
    self.name=name

def loadData(self, size=1, cost=1):
    self.size=size  
    self.cost=cost
```

In the main file I:

1. call the subfile,
2. create a list of data names
3. loop through the list to instantiate the objects; and
4. load data using 'loadData' method for each object (I'm using the same 'size' and 'cost' to make this example easy.)

```
    from subfile import StrucData 

    listIndex=['data1','data2','data3']

    # Create a list of objects
    listObjects=[]

    # Iterate through the list of objects
    for i in range(3):
        data=StrucData(listIndex[i])
        data.loadData(size=3, cost=4)
        listObjects.append(data)
```

What I am trying to do is doing the same thing using list comprehension, to obtain

```
listObjects=[object1, object2, object3]
```

and I have tried something like

```
listObjects=[[StrucData(listIndex[i]) for k in range(3)] listObjects[i].loadData(size=3, cost=4) for i in range(3)]]
```

which doesn't work of course, but I don't know how to do it properly.

Could I please have advice on my code to obtain the desired outputs using a list comprehension??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are free to append `return self` to the last line of `StrucData.loadData()` within `subfile.py`, it could be simplified like this:

```
# in the main file
listObjects = [StrucData(idx).loadData(size=3, cost=4) for idx in listIndex]
```

Otherwise, you have to do this separately because `loadData()` won't return anything for a list comprehension expression.

```
listObjects = [StrucData(idx) for idx in listIndex]
for i in range(3):
    listObjects[i].loadData(size=3, cost=4)
```

Comment: I would prefer the latter. But I must admit that I had thought of `(x.m(), x)[-1]` when I saw this.

Comment: You should not iterate on the indexes but on the items `for obj in listObjects:`.

Comment: @Guimoute I iterate over the index to emphasize the fact that changes are being made to the list items, just like the situation if  `listObjects = [1,2,3]` and you are going to add `1` to each element. It is a personal preference to make such logic explicit and you can of course disagree.

Comment: Thank you Bill. If you don't mind, I want to ask one more question. When I follow your first suggestion, the i-th object in listObject only contains its attributes 'size' and 'cost' excluding the method 'loadData'. But when I do instead:

x=  StrucData(listIndex[0]).loadData(size=3, cost=4)

the x includes the method 'loadData' in addition to the attributes too. Could you explain to me why it is the case? or show me how I can include the method in the object too?

Comment: Another question out of the scope of the original one should be post as a separate question. Please include what you have observed when detecting whether the `loadData` method exists or not. I think your method of detection is likely to be problematic. Please post exact what you observed instead of vague descriptions.

Comment: Thank you Bill. I followed your advice and posted more details here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65036850/objects-dos-not-include-methods-in-the-list-comprehension

I am not from computer science background, apologies if I am missing any key points here and there. 

After all, you helped me a lot on this question. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

Complementing Bill Huang's response, if you're not free to change the object and you don't want to iterate twice, you could add a helper function:

```py
def load_data(idx, size, cost):
    result = StructData(idx)
    result.loadData(size, cost)
    return result

[load_data(x, size=3, cost=4) for x in range(3)]
```

As a side-note, if you don't really need the instance to have the name and loadData separated, you could just use a namedtuple:

```py
from collections import namedtuple

StructData = namedtuple('StructData', ['name', 'size', 'cost'])
print([StructData(name=x, size=3, cost=4) for x in range(3)])
```

Wich would return:

```py
[StructData(name=0, size=3, cost=4), 
 StructData(name=1, size=3, cost=4), 
 StructData(name=2, size=3, cost=4)]
```

Finally, seeing that you have names such as "data1", "data2", you might want to have that as classnames, you can do so with namedtuple as long as names are valid class identifiers:

```py
from collections import namedtuple

list_index = ['data1', 'data2', 'data3']
print([namedtuple(name, ['size', 'cost'])(3, 4) for name in list_index])
```

Result:

```py
[data1(size=3, cost=4), data2(size=3, cost=4), data3(size=3, cost=4)]
```

Comment: Thank for nice suggestions David. In my example, I simplified many details, I cannot use some of your suggestions as it is. But these are definitely useful in other applications. Thanks a lot.