# Objects does not include methods in the list comprehension

Tags: python, list, object, list-comprehension, instantiation

This question is related to
[my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65021583/list-comprehensions-with-class-objects) and Bill's response there.

I have a class named StrucData in subfile.py

```
class StrucData:  
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name=name
    
    def loadData(self, size=1, cost=1):
        self.size=size  
        self.cost=cost
        return self
```

In the main file I:

1. call the subfile,
2. create a list of data names
3. loop through the list to instantiate the objects; and
4. load data using 'loadData' method for each object (I'm using the same 'size' and 'cost' to make this example easy.)

in one go using a list comprehension:

```
# in the main file

from subfile import StrucData 

listIndex=['data1','data2','data3']
listObjects = [StrucData(idx).loadData(size=3, cost=4) for idx in listIndex]
```

The output is

```
listObjects=[object1, object2, object3]
```

in which each object contains its attributes defined in the subfile.py (name, size, cost).
[image]

What I wonder is when I define one object using the same code as

```
x=StrucData(listIndex[0]).loadData(size=3, cost=4)
```

it contains the method 'loadData' too.
[image]

Could anyone please explain to me why it happens?

I use anaconda3 distribution of Spyder, the version information is
[image]

Comment: Your indentation is incorrect. As you have it now, one can't tell whether `loadData` is intended to be a method of class `StructData` notwithstanding it has `self` argument and this inspector-type listing you show says it is. But then, why are you asking why `loadData` is showing up as a method? Why wouldn't it?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the mistake and correcting it. My local version was correctly indented. So I will vote for Patrick's answer below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inspector used when debugging your application inside Spyder treats objects inside lists differently from singular objects of the same type. It simply displays different things and - if in a list - omits function.

You can easily check if both objects have this method by printing it:

```
listIndex = ['data1','data2','data3']
listObjects = [StrucData(idx).loadData(size=3, cost=4) for idx in listIndex]

other = StrucData("other").loadData(size=3, cost=4) 

print(listObjects[0].loadData)
print(other.loadData)
```

You can assign one of the list elements to a normal variable and check its inspector output to verify:

```
lO = listObjects[1]
```

Set a breakpoint and inspect it - now the method shows up.

As to the why: ask the coders responsible for Spyder's debugging inspector code. As a hazarded guess: to save screen estate when displaying objects that are bundled inside a list.